# Can the numbers 0 - 26 in ternary be arranged vertically such that digits appear in clusters of 3?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose you have a ternary number system with three glyphs (let's say 0, 1, 2). The numbers 0 - 26 are represented as three-digit strings of these three glyphs. You could count 000, 001, 002, 010, 011 etc. You list these 27 numbers vertically, for example:

\begin{matrix}
1&2&2\\
1&2&1\\
1&0&1\\
0&0&1\\
2&2&2\\
1&0&0\\
1&2&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{matrix}

As you can see, in the example above digits are arranged in clusters of three. By "cluster", I mean a group of similar digits that neighbor each other (a triomino of similar digits). Is it possible to arrange the entire set of 27 numbers this way?

Note: Groups of 6 similar digits are not allowed.

Comment: you must provide a strict definition of the conditions. Nice question. For 27 , the solution is easy to compute but in general for any basis and any numbers width, it seems that is a very hard question

Comment: @igael Did you have something specific in mind? The conditions seem well defined to me, but if there's any ambiguity let me know what it is. Thanks for the response.

Comment: by chance, it seems to be a squarred map. Do you count the diagonals ? how many matches do you compute with the sequence 000 012 021 ? 1 or 2 or is it prohibited ?

Comment: The sequence you describe, 000, 012, 021, when written out vertically contains one group of 5 zeroes, and four isolated numbers (groups/clusters of size 1). All of the 1's and 2's are isolated, as diagonals do not count. Numbers need to be horizontally or vertically adjacent to one another in order to belong to a group/cluster.

Comment: then no diagonal and a digit cannot belong to more than one cluster. Now, it's clear ...